# Display data from an specific frame in a .swf file through class, into an another .swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a .swf file wherein one of its frames have an integer value in which I wanted to print in another .swf file. I saved the value in that certain frame by using the 
"shareObject". The problem is that when I call it in another .swf file, my .as file will only read the very first frame of that .swf that's why it will return 0, and I'm pretty sure it was saved in my hard drive. It only works if I save the value in the very first frame, but I don't want to do that. Is there a way to get the value in a certain frame or any frame of an .swf file? I really need help. Any suggestion is very much appreciated. I'm using actionscript 3.0 by the way.

Here's my first .swf file where i save the value:(It's a code in one of its frames)

```
var saveRewardData:SharedObject;

var SaveReward1:int = 0;

SaveReward1 = 1;
saveData(); //<---Save reward data

init(); // this line goes directly beneath the variables

function init():void{ // call once to set everything up

    saveRewardData = SharedObject.getLocal("RewardInitializer"); // give the save data a location


     if(saveRewardData.data.savedScore == null){ // checks if there is save data

          trace("No saved data yet."); // if there isn't any data on the computer...
          saveRewardData.data.savedScore = SaveReward1; // ...set the savedScore to 0

     } else {
          trace("Save data found."); // if we did find data...
          loadData(); // ...load the data
     }
    }

    function saveData():void{

     saveRewardData.data.savedScore = SaveReward1; // set the saved score to the current score
     trace("Data Saved!");
     saveRewardData.flush(); // immediately save to the local drive
     trace(saveRewardData.size); // this will show the size of the save file, in bytes

    }

    function loadData():void{
     SaveReward1 = saveRewardData.data.savedScore; // set the current score to the saved score
     trace("Data Loaded!");
     trace(SaveReward1);

    }
```

Here's my .as file where in it calls the value of the first .swf file:

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


public class Reward1 extends Sprite 
{
   public var loader:Loader;

   public function Reward1()
{
     loader = new Loader();
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
     loader.load(new URLRequest("Level1.swf"));

}

public function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace("Child Loaded");
        trace(loader.content['SaveReward1']);

    }

    public function go0():int{

        return loader.content['SaveReward1'];
    }


}
}
```

Here's my second .swf file where in I print the value of 'SaveReward1' but it returns 0 because it was saved in the middle frame, and not in the first frame:

```
var got1:Reward1 = new Reward1();

got1.loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, reward1);


function reward1(e:Event):void {

trace(got1.go0());

}
```

Comment: Just access the SharedObject from the second SWF?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Can you give an example in accessing a sharedobject from another swf? I'm still learning actionscript 3 and I can't figure it out..

Comment: `var fromOtherSWF = SharedObject.getLocal("RewardInitializer");`

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal()

Comment: Specifically... "Returns a reference to a locally persistent shared object that is only available to the current client. If the shared object does not already exist, this method creates one."